# How to customize fields in django rest framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want to create a new record in database, I set a model like below:

```
class FooModel(models.Model)
    subject_key= models.CharField(max_length=2)
    subject= modeels.CharField(max_length=100)
```

What I want to do is this: field 'subject_key' should be given by the client, and using the subject_key, the server will find value 'subject' and put it in the database.

So I tried to use ModelSerializer to create a new record.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = FooModel

    def get_subject(self, obj):
        if obj.subject == 'SO':
            return 'Stack Overflow'
        else:
            return 'Nothing in here'
```

and main running code inside view rest api is:

```
class FooView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = FooSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            foo = serializer.data
```

I checked it successfully create a new record in database, but the new record has NULL with the column 'subject'

What should I do to dynamically set the field value inside serializer?

Comment: how you get subject value from request user or pass you request parameter

Comment: @Robert maybe I made you a little bit confused while shortening my code. I edtied it again, and I get subject_value from request.data when user requests for POST

Comment: after getting subject_vaule you need assign that value to subject_key right ??

Comment: @Robert Similar. After getting subject_key and I want to assign subject_value. I already made a dict { 'A': 'Apple', 'B': 'Banana' } something like this, and if I got 'A', I want to assign 'Apple' on the subject_value.

Comment: are got the ans if not understood let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declare your subject field in serializer as method field, it always read only ([serializermethodfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)), you can rename your filed for example:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FooModel

    def get_var_subject(self, obj):
```

in this way you will have tree fields in your seriaizer `'subject', 'subject_key', 'var_subject'`

OR you can add your mehod to the model and use `to_representation`

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(FooSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    representation['subject'] = instance.get_subject()
    return representation
```

OR use field [to_representation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example_1) example for related filed but i hope you can use it

OR you need to override `save` method

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['subject_key'] = request.data['subject']
        serializer = FooSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            foo = serializer.data
```